# Question about the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx^2}$ on $(0,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx^2}$ on $E = (0,1)$. If we allowed $x=0$, what would happen to the series? On one hand, we could write it as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (e^{-x^2})^n$ and it would become $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (1)^n$, clearly a divergent series. On the other hand, we could write it as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx^2}$, substitute and get: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}$. What is happening to the series here?

Comment: If $x=0$ surely the series would diverge: $1+1+1+\cdots \Rightarrow \infty?$ Also, what is the final series?

Comment: @Johnver, your ``On the other hand..." doesn't make sense as written. Did you make a typo with the second summation (which has no summand in it)?

Comment: $e^{-n0^2} = e^0 = 1$, so the order of operations doesn't change the fact that the term of the series is always $1$.

Comment: The term in the summand is 1 but there is no $n$ in there, which concerns me.

Comment: Say we have a constant function, $f(x) \equiv 3$. Then for each $x$ it returns $3$. Similarly, the $n^\text{th}$ term here is 1; if the series is $\sum_n a_n$, $a_n \equiv 1$, or $a(n) \equiv 1$. Coincidentally, $1^n$ means the same thing, since $1^n = 1$ for each $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the geometric series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n = \dfrac1{1-a}$$
In your case, $a=e^{-x^2}$. Hence, we obtain
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(e^{-x^2}\right)^n = \dfrac1{1-e^{-x^2}}$$
Note that $x \to 0$, $e^{-x^2} \to 1$, which implies $\dfrac1{1-e^{-x^2}} \to \infty$.